# Load image from JS to Phaser Game

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm doing a custom game which I'd like to change the background and a character picture according to a file they upload.
The input file is outside phaser. If possible, I'd like to show the picture directly without uploading to the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a file loader to get the base64 encoding of the image, you can use `this.textures.addBase64` to load the image into the texture manager, after that loads you can create new objects with that image tag, or set existing images to that texture.

Working Example =>
https://stackblitz.com/edit/phaser-use-uploaded-image